# Select rows from a table that are not in another where string length

Tags: mysql

In db MySQL I have two tables **xxx1** with 58 rows and **xxx2** with 71 rows.

The two tables are similar because in the column `name` on **xxx1** and **xxx2** I can have e.g. :

> VIETNAM 1/35 KHE SANH GUN POSITION BUNKER (

on **xxx2** table

and

> VIETNAM 1/35 KHE SANH GUN POSITION BUNKER (I) RESIN MODEL KIT

on **xxx1** table

If try this query on **xxx1** table the output is correct :

```
mysql> SELECT
    *
FROM
    `xxx1` r
WHERE
    r.name LIKE '%VIETNAM 1/35 KHE SANH ARTILLERY FIREBASE R%';
+----+----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name                                                     |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 30 | VIETNAM 1/35 KHE SANH ARTILLERY FIREBASE RESIN MODEL KIT |
+----+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

Now I need select rows from a table that are not in another and I have tried this query but the output is empty :

```
mysql> SELECT
    l.*
FROM
    xxx2 l
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            NULL
        FROM
            xxx1 r
        WHERE
            r.name LIKE '%VIETNAM 1/35 KHE SANH ARTILLERY FIREBASE R%'
    );
Empty set
```

What's the problem ?

How to do resolve this ?

Can you help me ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The way I would approach this is to `LEFT JOIN` the two tables and then identify records which do not match.  But your join condition is either not well defined or is complex and not easy to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `r.name LIKE '%VIETNAM 1/35 KHE SANH ARTILLERY FIREBASE R%'` will return a row based on the question, the `not exists` clause will be false for all records in xxx2, therefore an empty resultset is generated.

If you would like to know which record in xxx2 does not have  corresponding record in xxx1, where xxx2 content is the start of the content in xxx1, then use left join with `is null` condition:

```
select xxx2.name
from xxx2
left join xxx1 on xxx2.name=left(xxx1.name,char_length(xxx2.name))
where xxx1.name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        SELECT
    l.*
FROM
    xxx2 l
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            r.name
        FROM
            xxx1 r
        WHERE
            r.name LIKE concat('%',l.name,'%')
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.*
FROM xxx2 l
UNION
SELECT r.*
FROM xxx1 r where r.name LIKE '%VIETNAM 1/35 KHE SANH ARTILLERY FIREBASE R%'
```

Comment: Please provide explanation of your query in your answer, so that people will understand if/why/how it works.

Comment: Actually UNION will return all the rows from 2 tables without duplicate row and that is why I have used UNION here. If we want duplicate row as well then we can use UNION ALL.